# Compare two Type of Arraylist and return id

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I have two Arraylist. 
ArrayList workerlist  and Arraylist workernamelist

```
public class Workers {
    private String worker_id;
    private String worker_name;


    public String getWorker_id() {
        return worker_id;
    }

    public void setWorker_id(String worker_id) {
        this.worker_id = worker_id;
    }

    public String getWorker_name() {
        return worker_name;
    }

    public void setWorker_name(String worker_name) {
        this.worker_name = worker_name;
    }


}
```

The Arraylist workernamelist list contains all the worker name in strings.
I want to search through the ArrayList workerlist  weather it contains the wokrername in workerlist if it matches with the worker name then  it will return corresponding worker id .

Comment: Have tout considered using a 'Map'

Comment: Please mention where is your arraylist.can you show more code.

Comment: -1 Your question is hard to understand and you haven't supplied a code example of what you want to do. Make an attempt and post that, explaining what it does vs what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think we only need to traversal the whole workers list, and for each worker, compare it's name with the given worker_name, if they're equal, return the worker's id. If such worker does not exist or the worker_name is null you can return null.

```
public String findWorkerId(ArrayList<Workers> workerList, String workerName) {
    if (workerList == null || workerName == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (Workers worker : workerList) {
        if (workerName.equals(worker.getWorker_name())) {
            return worker.getWorker_id();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can do a great deal to to improve the quality of your answer by epxlaining why or how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Workers searchWorkers(ArrayList workers,String worker_name){
 int len = workers.size();
 for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
  your logic


    enter code here

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a for loop to look through the array list then if any match do display the match or whatever you want to do.

```
for(int i =0: i< workernamelist.size(); i++){
   if(workernamelist.worker_ID = worker_ID){
      system.out.println(workerlist.worker_ID);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    public String searchs(ArrayList list_workers,String worker_name){
     for(int i = 0; i<list_workers.size(); i++){
        if(list_workers.get(i).getWorker_name.equals(worker_name)
        {
            String worker_id=list_workers.get(i).getWorker_id();
            Log.d("TAG","worker_id:"+worker_id);
            return worker_id;
        }
      }

      return null;
    }
```

Comment: You have to check pass worker name  available in ArrayList  or not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
        ArrayList<String> workernamelist=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Workers> workersArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<workernamelist.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<workersArrayList.size();j++) {
                if (workernamelist.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(workersArrayList.get(j).getWorker_name()))
                {
                    String id=workersArrayList.get(j).getWorker_id();
                }
            }
        }
```